# What's the meaning of buzziest in this context?

Tags: meaning

This is the context:

> Seasoned travellers, especially the sort that jet around the globe clutching laptops, know that certain words are to be avoided like the plague. This is because those who choose these words are masters of disguise : the service offered is the exact opposite of that indicated by the name used to describe it. Thus many flights described as “direct” are actually indirect, since they involve a stop, and a lengthy wait, in, say, Dallas-Fort Worth en route between Boston and Vancouver. Similarly, habitués of railways learn to shun any train claiming to be an “express” or “rapid”, since such services seem invariably to be the slowest (by design, not just by accident). Which perhaps make it fitting that some of the most seasoned travellers of all, management consultants, appear to have been inspired by just this sort of untruth-in-advertising. ***The buzziest*** among them now claim not just to be consultants, or advisers, or even experts. They are “thought leaders”.

Comment: The ones trying to sound the most exciting? IMO though a 'thought leader' seems quite the opposite.

Comment: I have voted to reopen your other question. It already has an answer, and you've provided missing context there. You shouldn't be creating a new question that asks the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The buzziest** = the person/people who was/were buzzing most

Merriam-Webster: **Buzz** *(noun)* *1.e: speculative or excited talk or attention relating especially to a new or forthcoming product or event*

*"One of the few new shows that's getting good buzz."* — TV Guide

also : **an instance of such talk or attention** *"Their first CD created a huge buzz."*

Thus, "the person/people who was/were buzzing most" = the person/people who was/were talking in the most speculative and/or excited way *[especially in relation to]* to a new or forthcoming product, *[idea]* or event."